# Prevent Image.network from encoding image url

Tags: image, flutter, encode

I'm trying to display multiple images in a listview. So, I pass them to image.network(). When I run the app, I get the exception:

```
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404,
I/flutter ( 4820): https://cdn.mangacruzers.com/file/AnimeRleases/MHA_265_009.jpg%0D
```

It seems that '%0D' is appended to the url. In short, the url is being encoded when it is passed to Image.network(). Is there a way to prevent this encoding? I have already checked the list, the urls were not encoded before being passed to Image.network().

The code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: FutureBuilder(
              future: doc,
              builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData)
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                return ListView.builder(
                  primary: false,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: chapter.images.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                        child: Image.network(chapter.images[index]),
                      );
                    });
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Edit:

Data present in chapter.images -

```
 https://cdn.mangacruzers.com/file/AnimeRleases/MHA_265_001.jpg
I/flutter ( 4820): https://cdn.mangacruzers.com/file/AnimeRleases/MHA_265_002.jpg
I/flutter ( 4820): https://cdn.mangacruzers.com/file/AnimeRleases/MHA_265_003.jpg
I/flutter ( 4820): https://cdn.mangacruzers.com/file/AnimeRleases/MHA_265_4-5.png
I/flutter ( 4820): https://cdn.mangacruzers.com/file/AnimeRleases/MHA_265_6-7.png
I/flutter ( 4820): https://cdn.mangacruzers.com/file/AnimeRleases/MHA_265_008.jpg
I/flutter ( 4820): https://cdn.mangacruzers.com/file/AnimeRleases/MHA_265_009.jpg
I/flutter ( 4820): https://cdn.mangacruzers.com/file/AnimeRleases/MHA_265_10-11.png
I/flutter ( 4820): https://cdn.mangacruzers.com/file/AnimeRleases/MHA_265_012.jpg
I/flutter ( 4820): https://cdn.mangacruzers.com/file/AnimeRleases/MHA_265_013.jpg
I/flutter ( 4820): https://cdn.mangacruzers.com/file/AnimeRleases/MHA_265_014.jpg
I/flutter ( 4820): https://cdn.mangacruzers.com/file/AnimeRleases/MHA_265_015.jpg
I/flutter ( 4820): https://cdn.mangacruzers.com/file/AnimeRleases/MHA_265_016.jpg
I/flutter ( 4820): https://cdn.mangacruzers.com/file/AnimeRleases/MHA_265_017.jpg
I/flutter ( 4820): https://cdn.mangacruzers.com/file/AnimeRleases/MHA_265_18-19.png
```

Comment: something is wrong with the URL you're passing, not with the ``Image.network()``

%0D is a newline. Check your URL.

Comment: %0D isn't present in the list I've passed. The actual url is everything except %0D

Comment: can you post the data in `chapter.image`? I think there may be special character in the url.

Comment: As requested, I have added the data present in chapter.images

Comment: @U.Watt, please share the screenshot of ``chapter.images`` variable. Lines of codes where you're assigning or declaring URLs to the variable. You have shared logged data; share the actual lines of codes.

Comment: No need, the solution by Zakir worked.

Comment: Tha's okay, but definitely your URLs contained some extra characters at the end which caused the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

%0D is URL-encoding value for carriage return. You can encode your url and print it to see whether it contains any CR.

```
var encoded = Uri.encodeFull(chapter.images[index]);
print(encoded);
```

If it has any CR then you should replace it before assigning to Image.network().

```
var urlWithoutCR = chapter.images[index].replaceAll(RegExp(r'\r'), "");
Image.network(urlWithoutCR);
```